# CSS Row Aligning Issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i've some CSS problems. I made a row with images and some texts. But images' borders are not in alignment. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ7vk.jpg) about that. And my CSS codes which i am used:

```
.portfolyo-foto {
    width: 149px;
    margin-right: 1.2%;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    display: inline-table;
}

.portfolyo-cerceve {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
}

.leftTypeWrapperOuter {
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 13%;
}

.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you add your html code as well? @Katzenliebe

Comment: Add your html here or in a jsfiddle, not a link to your website, please.

Comment: It's not html. Here is my php file http://codepad.org/bKVbZ5Zt @Smit

Answer (score 0):

You should include the link in the div.

```
<div class="portfolyo-foto">
    <img width="100" height="100" src="" />
    <a href="#">All</a>
</div>
```

and add this rule in css:

```
.works-filter a,
.works-filter a.active{
    margin:0;
}
```

Also, remember it is a good practice to share all the needed code.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. My codes aren't html. Here are my codes: http://codepad.org/bKVbZ5Zt

Comment: @Katzenliebe If you can't change the php code, you should ask the person that wrote the code to do that for you. If not, all you have to do is to set the same margins for the images and the links.

Answer (score 0):

If you move your links to the bottom of images:

```
<div class="portfolyo-foto">
  <img src="http://ailuros.bursasinemalari.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/placeholder.png" width="100" height="100">
  <a href="#" class="filter active" data-filter="*">All</a>
</div>
```

and apply the following css:

```
.works-filter {
    width: 100%;
}
.works-filter a {
    margin: 0; /* overwriting previous margin: 0 5px */
}
```

you'll get:

[image]

---

**Update**: Repositioning the a tags in the template

```
// temporary array to hold a tags
$a_tags = [];

$portfolioTagsArray = array();
$postCounter = 0;
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        $postCounter++;
            $t = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'ff-portfolio-tag' );
            if( !empty($t) ) foreach ($t as $onePortfolioTag) {
                if( !isset($portfolioTagsArray[ $onePortfolioTag->slug ]) ) {
                    // instead of creating a really long string which contains multiple a tags
                    // store the a tags individually inside an array
                    $a_tags[] = '<a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".tag-'.esc_attr($onePortfolioTag->term_id).'">'.ff_wp_kses( $onePortfolioTag->name ).'</a>';
                }
                $portfolioTagsArray[ $onePortfolioTag->slug ] = $onePortfolioTag;
            }
            if( $numberOfPosts > 0 && $postCounter >= $numberOfPosts ) {
                break;
            }
    }
}

$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array('taxonomy' => 'ff-portfolio-tag'));

// now I think, length of $terms array and $a_tags array are equal
// and their items correspond with each other
// if so, what you need to do is
// when you print the div.portfolyo-foto and the img
// simply add the corresponding a tag before closing the div
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( (array) $terms as $key => $term ) {
        print '<div class="portfolyo-foto">';
        print wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'taxonomy-thumb' );
        print $a_tags[$key]; // $key should be index, e.g. 0,1,2,3, etc.
        print '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks "All" button seems nice now. But now the others have problem. Here are my php codes: http://codepad.org/bKVbZ5Zt

Comment: Can you post your previous and current php code? The last 4 `.portfolyo-foto` s are stacked inside each other. What did you change? I'm not really familiar with WordPress. Comparing the old and the new php might help.

Comment: @Katzenliebe Updated my answer. See if you can make it work.

Comment: Many thanks for your patience. I couldn't get result. But big thanks to you. Theme files are very complicated. I will get rid of black backgrounds of the filter texts. It will help may be. @akinuri